Modal verbs can't vs couldn't
Does "can't and couldn't" mean the same thing in the present tense. Let me give examples
1 I can't help you tomorrow
2 I couldn't help you tomorrow
3 It can't be the truth
4 It couldn't be the truth
To me they all have pretty much the same meaning. Thus, these two modals are interchsngeable. Do you agree?

I can't help you tomorrow is a statement of fact. I couldn't introduces an element of irrealis.

I couldn't help you tomorrow even if I wanted to, because I'm going to London to see my cousin. (In fact, the speaker is unwilling to help.)

